# R plot.gam Error "Error in 1:object$nsdf : argument of length 0"

Tags: r, plot, regression, gam, mgcv

I am trying to plot a gam object in R, which I made with the gam package. I receive the same error reported in [Error in 1:object$nsdf : argument of length 0 when using plot.gam](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35699399/4769229). However, the solution found there, updating to the latest versions (I think), is not working for me. I am running R 3.3.1, gam 1.12, and mgcv 1.8.12 (mgcv is where the plot.gam function is from).

Unfortunately, I cannot share the data I am working with. However, the following code -- pulled directly from the p.294 of Intro. to Statistical Learning with R -- reproduces the error for me:

```
library(gam)
library(ISLR) # contains the Wage dataset used here
gam.mod <- gam(wage ~ s(year, 4) + s(age, 5) + education, data = Wage)
plot(gam.mod)
```

Does anybody know what is going on here or how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still get this message, you need to update your `mgcv` and `gam` package to the latest version. A big change was made to `gam` package in Feb, 2018: [Could not find function plot.gam](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51158531/4891738). This means, a GAM fitted by `gam` package now have "Gam" class, and even if `mgcv` package is loaded, `plot` will not choose `mgcv::plot.gam` to plot it.

However, it is still unsafe to have both packages in an R session. So the following suggestion made in 2016 is still highly recommended.

---

**Suggestion**

It might be a good idea have this toy function to check whether an R session is OK to run GAM analysis.

```
GAM_status <- function () {
  if (all(c("gam", "mgcv") %in% .packages())) print("Not OK")
  else print("OK")
  }
```

---

`nsdf` is the **the number of strict degree of freedom**, a term exclusively used in `mgcv`. As you mentioned: `mgcv` is where the `plot.gam` function is from.

The problem is that you have `gam` and `mgcv`, two incompatible packages in your R session at the same time. You fit your `gam.mod` with `gam::gam`, but then plot the model with `mgcv::plot.gam`.

Note, what is normally true by using `::` will lose effect here. Normally when two packages have some inter-masked functions, the `::` is the remedy. But, for `mgcv` and `gam`, this is completely impossible. So my suggestion is, if you use `gam`, do not ever touch `mgcv` in your R session, and vice versa.

So, I start a fresh R session, and do the following, everything is fine!

```
library(gam)
library(ISLR) # contains the Wage dataset used here
gam.mod <- gam(wage ~ s(year, 4) + s(age, 5) + education, data = Wage)
par(mfrow = c(2,2)); plot(gam.mod)
```

[image]

---

> Thank you for your answer. I never actually loaded `mgcv`, I just assumed it was a dependency for `gam`. I started a fresh R session and the code you provided worked. I found that it is actually the `car` library that is causing the same issue.

`mgcv` and `gam` does not depend on each other, but since `mgcv` is more popular than `gam`, many packages has dependency on `mgcv`, for example, [`car`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/index.html):

```
car: Companion to Applied Regression

Functions and Datasets to Accompany J. Fox and S. Weisberg, An R  Companion to
Applied Regression, Second Edition, Sage, 2011.
Version:    2.1-3
Depends:    R (≥ 3.2.0)
Imports:    MASS, mgcv, nnet, pbkrtest (≥ 0.4-4), quantreg, grDevices, utils,
            stats, graphics
```

Note the "Imports" field, `library(car)` will load these packages at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

My `mgcv` version is 1.8-28, but I still have this issue. Consider converting all char variables into factors and rerun `gam()` or `bam()`. It works for me.