# Could not find function plot.gam

Tags: r, plot, syntax, package, gam

I'm going through the "Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R" (ISLR), and I'm stuck on a part on page 295, the lab on Generalized Additive Models. When I run the following code I get an error `Error in plot.gam(gam1, se = TRUE, col = "red") : could not find function "plot.gam"`.

```
library(ISLR)
gam1 = lm(wage ~ ns(year, 4) + ns(age, 5) + education, data=Wage)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot.gam(gam1, se=TRUE, col="red")
```

The book says that `plot.gam` should be part of the general `plot` function, so why can't R find it? Am I supposed to be doing something differently? I tried unsuccessfully to re-download the plot library with `install.packages('plot', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`.

This confuses me because the book says this:

> The generic plot() function recognizes that gam2 is an object of class
>   gam, andinvokestheappropriateplot.gam()method.Conveniently,eventhough
>   plot.gam() gam1 is not of class gam but rather of class lm, we can
>   still use plot.gam() on it. Figure 7.11 was produced using the
>   following expression:
>
> > plot.gam(gam1, se=TRUE, col="red")

Comment: @李哲源 I've tried library(gam) too but it doesn't help. I also cleared my workspace and re-entered everything.

Comment: I think you want the package `mgcv`

Comment: With `library(mgcv)`, I don't get the same error but I get `Error in if (se && x$Vp[1, 1] < 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`... This is weird because the book seemed to expect me to be able to just use `plot.gam` without importing anything. I had been told to import `gam` earlier though.

Comment: Do you mean `plot.Gam` then? Remember R is case sensitive. Also you can check which methods are available for regular `plot` (which is a function, not a package) by calling `methods(plot)`. There doesn't appear to be one for gam so I'm not sure why the book says that

Comment: `plot.Gam` works! Thanks - I didn't know about `methods()`, super useful. No idea why the book was able to use `plot.gam`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `plot.Gam` not `plot.gam`.

Software updates, but the book has not kept up. Checking the [change log for the `gam` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gam/ChangeLog), we can see that the case was changed in early 2018:

> 2018-02-06   Trevor Hastie  version 1.15
>       * major change class "gam" to "Gam" to avoid conflict with mgcv (grr!)